# add script right after opening body tag in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

how can i add a script right after opening body tag in magento 1.9 ?

i aready tried this
[How to add code after opening <body> tag in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85781/how-to-add-code-after-opening-body-tag-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

Open your theme layout update file (preferably local.xml). Use the after_body_start container. You can put the JavaScript in a template:

```
<reference name="after_body_start">
    <block type="core/template" name="any_unique_name_here" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Or add it as a text block directly in XML:

```
<reference name="after_body_start">
    <block type="core/text" name="any_unique_name_here">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('It works!');
</script>
]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Tested code,It will work for sure (Don't forget to clear cache after applying changes)